# Paste Special issue when merging conditional formats in Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2016

I have a simple macro that copies a cell into another cell, merging conditional formatting:

```
Sub test()

   Range("A2").Copy

   Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

The content of A2 is `1` and the conditional rule is simply `=ISODD($A2)`.
When I execute the macro in Excel 2016 Mac I get this error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Range' failed

The same macro works perfectly in Excel for Windows.

If I change the `XlPasteType` option with `xlPasteAll` instead of  `xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats`, the macro is executed without errors.

Comment: Try to replace `xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats` with `14`. Object browser says : `Const xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats = 14`

Comment: Solved...I have no words...Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not have all the enumeration and properties in VBA for Mac, so you can replace this by its value directly.

Here replace `xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats` with **14**.

Because Object Browser (F2 in VBE) says :

```
Const xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats = 14
```

Comment: Yes I did it and the problem is solved. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you plz validate the answer as you problem is solved? And take a minute to go through the tour plz : http://stackoverflow.com/tour